# Why does .NET 4.0 give a "CRT not initialized" error when loading an unmanaged DLL?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, .net-4.0, crt

I have a DLL supplied by a 3rd party along with an accompanying .NET 2.0 assembly that wraps it. If I create a .NET 3.5 project with VS2008 I am able to call into the DLL via the wrapper assembly and it works OK. However, if I create an equivalent .NET 4.0 project with VS2010 then I get a `R6030 - CRT not initialized` error in a message box at the time the DLL is loaded.

Is there something I can do to get this to work in a .NET 4.0 project? Could it be related to the CAS changes, or something else?

I'm carrying on with my work in VS2008 for now, but it would be good to understand what's happening...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a .NET error, it is a MS C Runtime (CRT, MSCRT) error.

Your 3rd party dll is presumably using some MSCRT dll (there are lots of versions). At process start up of a native application the CRT is initialised (it contains the program entry point which then calls `main`). There is also an entry point for new threads to ensure per-thread data is set up correctly.

If .NET 2 runtime<sup>[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28VS.71%29.aspx)</sup> by default uses the same MSCRT as the native code then it will be correctly initialised. .NET 4 presumably uses a newer version (new MSCRT versions tend to come with new versions of VS, as .NET does) then the older MSCRT is only being loaded as a dependency and not used for application startup.

Most of the time MSCT handles this correctly, but if the 3rd party dll is doing something "clever" it might be bypassing some initialisation, and this just happens to work is the same version of MSCRT is used by .NET. An example of such incorrect usage is to directly call `CreateThread` rather than using the MSCRT [`_beginthread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28VS.71%29.aspx) wrapper.

To root cause this you will need sufficient understanding of the 3rd part dll and wrapper—more likely you need to supply a re-create to the third party for them to fix.

---

<sup>[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28VS.71%29.aspx)</sup> Remember V3.5 is just extra assemblies on top of the 2.0 CLI.

Comment: That fits with what I'm seeing; it just happens that the 2.0 CLR uses the correct CRT version. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does it happen only on debugging or also in running as well?

Two things come into mind:

1) Default application type for .NET is targeted at .NET Client Framework which is most annoying and I have to change it all the time. You could get all sorts of wierd errors if you keep it as client which at face have nothing to do it. Try changing that.

2) Do you need VS 2010 or .NET 4.0? If only VS 2010 then you can set the target framework to 3.5 and try to see if the problem is VS 2010 or .NET 4.0.

From looking at the error on internet, it looks like this is a timing issue and C runtime is not loaded - a behaviour which looks like changed in .NET 4.0. I have no idea how to fix it.